# Inner Join on a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I got the following TICKET table:

```
DELIVERY_CODE,
TICKET_ID,
TIME_SMTP
```

The Delivery code has `5 values (100001,100002,100003,100004,100005)`

I want to find out which ticket_id's have not been delivered with DELIVERY_CODE 100002 but had previously `DELIVERY_CODE 1000001`. All the ticket_id's have been delivered initally with `DELIVERY_CODE: 100001`

So I should make a inner join on the table like this?

```
SELECT (SELECT *
FROM TICKET A
WHERE DELIVERY_CODE =  '1000001')
FROM TICKET
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM TICKET B
           WHERE DELIVERY_CODE =  '1000002')
    ON A.TICKET_ID = B.TICKET_ID
WHERE B.TICKET_ID IS NULL`
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is not an `INNER JOIN`...

Comment: what is your problem, did you get an error or unexpected result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `where exists`

```
select A1.*
from Ticket A1
where A1.Delivery_Code = '1000002'
and exists (select 1 
            from Ticket A2 
            where A1.Ticket_ID = A2.TicketID 
            and A2.Ticket_ID = '1000001')
```

Ok, following a re-read of the question, you can conversely use a `not exists`

```
select A1.*
from Ticket A1
where A1.Delivery_Code = '1000001'
and not exists (select 1 
                from Ticket A2 
                where A1.Ticket_ID = A2.TicketID 
                and A2.Ticket_ID = '1000002')
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select t.ticket_id
from ticket t
where sum(case when t.delivery_code = '1000001' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
      sum(case when t.delivery_code = '1000002' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `sum(case)` counts the number of rows that match each delivery code.  The `> 0` means there is at least one; the `= 0` means there are none.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM TICKET A
LEFT JOIN TICKET B 
   ON A.TICKET_ID = B.TICKET_ID AND A.TIME_SMTP < B.TIME_SMTP AND
      B.DELIVERY_CODE =  '1000002'
LEFT JOIN TICKET C
   ON A.TICKET_ID = C.TICKET_ID AND A.TIME_SMTP < C.TIME_SMTP AND
      C.DELIVERY_CODE <>  '1000002'
WHERE A.DELIVERY_CODE = '1000001' AND B.TICKET_ID IS NULL AND C.TICKET_ID IS NOT NULL
```

`B` is used to check that no ticket with `DELIVERY_CODE = '1000002'` exists. `C` is used to check that at least one ticket with `DELIVERY_CODE <> '1000002'` exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.DELIVERY_CODE
FROM TICKET a
     LEFT JOIN TICKET b ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
                           AND b.DELIVERY_CODE = '1000002'
WHERE a.DELIVERY_CODE = '1000001'
      AND b.ticket_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you mentioned "inner join" but implemented "left join", so it is not clear which of them you meant (although if any, left join is indeed what you are looking for).

However, I think you better use a sub-query for this one. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TICKET A
WHERE DELIVERY_CODE = '1000001'
AND TICKET_ID NOT IN (SELECT TICKET_ID
                FROM TICKET 
                WHERE DELIVERY_CODE = '1000002'
                    AND TICKET_ID != A.TICKET_ID)
```

Anyway, I want to point out a mistake you have on this current code of yours:

```
SELECT (SELECT *
FROM TICKET A
WHERE DELIVERY_CODE =  '1000001')
FROM TICKET
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
        FROM TICKET B
        WHERE DELIVERY_CODE =  '1000002')
    ON A.TICKET_ID = B.TICKET_ID
WHERE B.TICKET_ID IS NULL`
```

A and B are exist only under the scope of the sub-quires, but not out of them, so you could not use "on" over them.  Plus, you cannot select inside the select statement.

Didn’t you get a syntax error?